# Why is `npm run dev` not working on a fresh `npx create-next-app`?

Tags: next.js, npx

I just created a new Next app with `npx create-next-app`. It seems to have run successfully:

```
$ npx create-next-app                                                             [8:46:31]

npx: installed 1 in 8.826s
✔ What is your project named? … sightsee
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS with this project? Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? Yes
✔ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project? No
✔ What import alias would you like configured? … @/*
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/name/sideProjects/sightsee.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: default-tw


...
... irrelevant output
...
+ typescript@5.0.4
+ next@13.3.0
added 329 packages from 271 contributors and audited 338 packages in 182.455s

116 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Success! Created sightsee at /Users/name/sideProjects/sightsee.
```

Then I `cd sightsee; npm run dev`:

```
name@MacBook-Pro-3: ~/sideProjects/sightsee main!
$ npm run dev                                                                     [9:30:12]

> sightsee@0.1.0 dev /Users/name/sideProjects/sightsee
> next dev


name@MacBook-Pro-3:~/sideProjects/sightsee main!
```

Usually it says something like `running on port localhost:3000`.

`npm run build`

```
$ npm run build                                                                   [9:29:43]

> sightsee@0.1.0 build /Users/name/path/project next build

uncaughtException Error: Cannot find module 'node:buffer'
...
...
FAIL
```

I just created this project, why is nothing working?

I tried reinstalling node modules, reinstalling npx, all had no effect.

Why is `npx create-next-app` creating an app that can't run?

Answer (score 1):

Check the node version you are currently using, if it's an old version you might be given this error;

In order to check the current version running

> node -v

For updating to a new LTS version

> nvm install 18

Make sure that nvm is using the new version before running npm run dev or build

> nvm use 18

Then

> npm run build

Comment: This still happens to me on `v18.17.1` any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out – the problem is that I was previously working in another directory that required an old version of node (6.14.8!), so in my `sideProjects` folder I ran `echo "18.5.0" > .nvmrc`, then `nvm use`, to use the latest version. Then I deleted the old app and ran the same thing again, and now it all works!

:D hope this helps someone